# Optimizing Code - CPU vs Memory

Tags: c++, c, performance, algorithm, memory

I'm trying to optimize some algorithms in the core of my program and I'm wondering what part of the hardware really "slows down" everything.

The probably two most important parts of the hardware when it comes to programming are the CPU and the RAM (and the Cache memory of the CPU???). But how do they play together when it comes to performance?

Consider this block of code:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
for(int count = 0; count < 100000; count++)
{
    vec.push_back(count);
}
```

In this case, the part which really slows down the algorithm is the speed at which memory is  written to the RAM(?). The speed of the CPU is hardly going to take any impact on the execution time of this code, since there's not much to calculate, right?

But now, consider this block of code:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
for(int count = 0; count < 100000; count++)
{
    vec.push_back(count/10/10/10/10);
}
```

In this case, several arithmetic operations are executed (on the CPU) before inserted into the list (on the RAM). Is there going to be a big performance impact in this case? The CPU has to first calculate the result and THEN the result can be written to the RAM, so it has to be definitely slower, right?

If this is correct, then (as far as I see it) the part which REALLY slows down programs is  the SPEED at which can be written to the RAM and not the speed of the CPU, right? Because even if have a more complex block of code, it will always be in the form:

```
//calculate something and write it to the RAM
int something = calculateSomething();
```

There will always be arithmetic operations, as well as memory allocations. But I rarely see the CPU being working on 100 % when looking at the Task Manager - which concludes that there has to be another part which slows down the whole thing.

To bring it to the point:
What is the most important thing I have to consider when optimizing an algorithm? Allocating less memory and recalculating values more often which increases CPU work and decreases memory allocation - or calculation values only once and writing them to the memory? What is going to bring me more performance out of my algorithm?
And what are the parts in modern hardware today that REALLY slow down code to be as fast as it is?

Thanks already in advance.

Comment: 1) http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

2) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29

3) Fix the hot path.

4) Have a bear.

Comment: With a vector that size, a lot of time will be spent reallocating the space for the vector.  If you wish to optimize, preallocate the space.

Comment: @nonsensickle Won't the bear just eat me?!

Comment: You will learn a lot by reading this article on the performance impact of memory written by one of the authors of the C library: http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf

Comment: The answer is, "it depends." The most important thing, after you know that your algorithm works, is to profile your code and determine where it's slow. Then you determine whether it's CPU bound, memory access bound, I/O bound, etc., and what is the cause of the bottleneck. That's going to differ for every algorithm.

Comment: @JasonCoco In Russia, we eat the bears!

Answer (score 3):

Even with today's hardware some things can be estimated to some extend:  The performance of arithmetic operations is somewhat predictable,  you can calculate the required time for a set of operations as the sum of the time required for the individual operations.  Roughly, up to a factor of two or so.  Unfortunately with most other operations this is not possible.  Reading a value from memory can take anywhere from 1 to 200 clock cycles.  The figures for a conditional jump are similar, depending on branch prediction and the caching state of the code you jump to.  And because those operations typically take most of the performance, you can rarely guess bottlenecks just from looking at the code.  **Use a profiler and be prepared for a few surprises.**  Calculating a square root can be faster than reading the result from memory.  A O(n^2) algorithm can be faster than a O(n) algorithm.  In some cases the compiler might even turn one into the other if it can prove the result remains the same.

Comment: Clear answer, thank you. Can you guide me to a profiler for windows which is able to profile CPU as well as memory allocation? Most of what I've found is just able to sample the CPU.

Answer (score 3):

> In this case, the part which really slows down the algorithm is the speed at which memory is written to the RAM(?).

No, the part that really slows down the algorithm is not hardware, but the implementation of the C++ vector, which relies heavily on dynamic memory allocation. It will have to re-size the vector over and over in that loop. Furthermore, it will lead to heap fragmentation. All of this will be the major bottleneck.

Had you used a plain "C style" array, the bottleneck might have been CPU or the RAM access time. It depends on what hardware the code runs on. Data cache memory isn't likely going to be of any help, since you don't use the data immediately after writing to it.

> In this case, several arithmetic operations are executed (on the CPU) before inserted into the list

No, the compiler has already translated your code to `count/10000`. So there is one CPU division instruction. It will not have a great impact on performance on a 32-bit CPU or larger. On an 8-bit CPU it would lead to a severe performance degradation, because it won't likely be able to perform division on large numbers in an effective manner.

> If this is correct

As you can see from the above, most of it isn't.

> But I rarely see the CPU being working on 100 % when looking at the Task Manager - which concludes that there has to be another part which slows down the whole thing.

On a PC, there is an OS running in the background. So there is pretty much always something being executed, apart from the applications running on top of the OS. Scheduling and the number of physical CPU cores will also determine how many % of the CPU that is used. And of course, every kind of hardware plays part, not only RAM but also HD access times.

> What is the most important thing I have to consider when optimizing an algorithm?

The most important thing is to ask yourself the following questions:

- Is there a real need to optimize this piece of code? Is there a real bottleneck which you have benchmarked, or are you seeing problems where there exist none the real world?
- Do you actually know how the pre-processor and compiler's optimizer work?
- Do you actually know how a compiler translates C++ code into machine code?
- Do you have in-depth hardware knowledge of the given system, to the point where you know more about the hardware than the people who made the compiler port for the given hardware? Do you have in-depth knowledge of the hardware optimizing features of the CPU, such as pipelining, data/instruction cache, branch predication?

**It does not make any sense to manually optimize code without a specific hardware in mind.**

> And what are the parts in modern hardware today that REALLY slow down code to be as fast as it is?

Modern hardware is most often ridiculously fast... in case of a PC, any hard drive access is a likely hardware bottleneck. But most of the things that actually do slow down your code are software. Data shuffling and nested loops in your program. Bombastic libraries and various runtime crap used by your application. The incredibly sluggish desktop OS with hundreds of other programs running at once. And so on.

Comment: "the pre-processor has already translated your code to count/10000." => not the preprocessor but the _compiler_ :)

Comment: @JensSchwarzer Hmm ok fair enough :)

Comment: Also `count/10000` will not necessarily be a division instruction but will probably end up being a multiplication by a fixed-point reciprocal.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are thinking, similar things might not be happening at the back end.
Nowadays compilers are smart enough to optimize your programs as much as possible.
so your thinking (count/10/10/10/10) will be optimized with (count/10000) if any other program logic is not varying.

Another thing in your code I found is: if you know the size of the vector already, then allocate it in the first place that may improve your performance a bit. As for finding new place to store data every time increases the unnecessary computations.

Another case though CPU speed is much higher than memory, you can't just say that problem is with memory and not with CPU. Profile your code once and find out where the actual bottleneck is.